# big mysql database count distinct performance

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I have a big problem. I have a table with around 50M rows. And in this table I have 3 columns: location, code of a person, and date. It looks something like this:

```
date         person    location

2012-04-07   837592      0
2012-04-08   892857      6
2012-04-06   726474      1
2012-04-03   204857      4
2012-04-08   516485      9
2012-04-07   405867      0
```

So a person can be at different locations at the same date or at the same location on different dates.

Now, my problem is that I need a query like:

`SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT person) FROM my_table WHERE location = '0';`

So basically I have to count different persons that was on one place at different times. And if I do this in a way previously described the query takes around 20min.

So i am asking if there is a faster way of doing this?

Comment: how much do you think i need here and keep in mind i get 20M rows a month

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
SELECT person, COUNT (*) FROM my_table WHERE location = '0' group by person;
```

This will improve the performance, The next you can do like indexing the column used.

Comment: i tried this and it takes the same amount of time.
plus i have tried indexing and it didnt seem to work.

Comment: @tilen:   Please show me the construct of the table, along with the explain plan

Comment: construct of the table?

id>1 ;  select type>simple  ; table>vse , type>ref , possible keys>datum_2 , key>datum_2 , key_len>607 , ref>cons,cons , rows 765 , extra> useing where;useing index

Comment: @tilen: Please execute the command "Show create table tableName" and please show me the out put, and the explain plan

Comment: CREATE TABLE `vse` (\n  `datum` varchar(200) default NULL,\n  `ura` int(11) default NULL,\n  `resip` bigint(20) default NULL,\n  `medcode` int(11) default NULL,\n  KEY `datum_2` (`datum`,`ura`,`resip`,`medcode`)\n) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: Is there any index on the location? and what is its datatype, since the construct is different from the example you provided and please provide the explain plan too

Comment: sory i have the titles in my own language so datum and ura are date and time resip is person and medcode is the location no the location doesnt have an index since i have heard that the index needs to be on the left most prefix and i usualy use date and the location in where clause. the explain i have provided for u in the third comment. thx

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM my_table WHERE location = '0' GROUP BY person;
```